# scroll in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an android app in phonegap. I want to select multiple options and these options should be visible in a row whenever I swipe the option bar. I also want to navigate multiple pages on swipe. How can I do this? can anyone help me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation will be useful IScroll http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4.

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
    <li></li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
</script>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: /*your height*/;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

All except "wrapper" will be static.