# scrolling on touch devices for phonegap/cordova projects

Tags: android, iphone, scroll, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontally scrollable image on Android + PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303589/horizontally-scrollable-image-on-android-phonegap-jquery-mobile)

how to provide scroll effect to phonegap projects on android/iphone.
i've tried using [Jquery](http://jquerymobile.com/),[iscroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) and also jquery package for iscroll but all these have some problems. is there any other better alternative for providing native scroll effect on touch devices Android and Iphone.??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618221/scroll-in-phonegap-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iScroll4 is as close as you can get to native scrolling with phonegap, IMHO. If performance is poor, consider simplifying your list item layouts down to a level where scrolling performance is acceptable, or if possible, find a way that makes sense to the end user to limit the data set used for each list. If iScroll4's performance still isn't good enough for your app, your probably need to consider developing native apps for each platform.

Comment: but iscroll 4 has several problems the buttons and input text doesnt work quite well when using iscroll

Comment: "The buttons and input text doesnt work quite well" is too unspecific. The frameworks you mentioned are the most widely used and if you don't want to go native you'll have to settle for one of them unless you want to implement your own scroll solution. Perhaps the best way to get help is to post the code to one of your jQuery or iScroll4 attempts and specify your issue with it.